# Task is running to completion, even though it is not completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, prism

I am running into an issue that I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't seem to be awaiting properly.

I have a recursive file copy that is asyncronous which is shown below:

```
public async Task CopyFiles(string source, string destination)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
    }

    var info = new DirectoryInfo(source);

    foreach (var file in info.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        Progress.Report(new Counter { Files = 1, FileSize = file.Length, Log = $"Copying file {file.Name}" });
        try
        {
            var newpath = Path.Combine(destination, file.Name);
            if (File.Exists(newpath) && File.GetLastWriteTime(newpath) == file.LastWriteTime)
            {
                continue;
            }

            using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(newpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await reader.CopyToAsync(writer);
                }

            }

            File.SetLastAccessTime(newpath, file.LastAccessTime);
            File.SetLastWriteTime(newpath, file.LastWriteTime);
            File.SetAttributes(newpath, file.Attributes);

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    foreach (var directory in info.EnumerateDirectories())
    {
        try
        {
            await CopyFiles(directory.FullName, $"{destination}\\{directory.Name}");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

This method is called with DelegateCommand in Prism

```
        private async Task RestoreFiles()
    {
        var progress = GetProgressReporter();

        var recursion = new Recursion(progress, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));
        await recursion.CopyFiles(@"\\800CRBackup\Backups\Profiles\Beta\" + $"{Environment.UserName}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)));

        ResetStats();
    }
```

When running the debugger, it believes that the Task has ran to completion. However this doesn't seem to be the case because the Progress reporter in the method subtracts the total remaining files left to copy which is bound to the ViewModel.

The ResetStats method sets the files remaining, size remaining and current log to 0.

But since the recursive copy is still occurring even though it said the Task finished, it causes my UI to go into the negative numbers.

The only way for me to fix it is to wrap the recursion into a Task.Run, but at that point there's no point of me trying to do it asynchronously.

My best guess of what is happening here is something to do with async void from an event handler but not sure how I would resolve it as Commands are voids.

Comment: Are you getting some errors that you are not handling in catch? And there is not a lot to be achieved with async in this case it will probably just end up slowing the app down since you are not dealing with high concurrency.

Comment: If you do not have permission to create the directory the code will do nothing.

Comment: The Task completes without an exception, I also surrounded it with a try catch block to throw an exception and nothing was caught as well.

Comment: Yeah I am aware that the code will fail if there's no permission available in the directory creation, but in this case I do have permissions. The code works fine, the only issue is the awaited Task finishes before it is really finished. It also works fine if it is wrapped in a Task.Run in a new thread as well.

Comment: I see neither something `async void` nor an event nor a `DelegateCommand`... can you post the relevant code?

Comment: I figured out the issue, but not sure how to resolve it. Essentially, the UI is updating too fast and causing it to freeze for about a second, which then causes the await to end earlier than it should. If I add a millisecond delay to each progress report, it works. But I don't know how I can fix it without using a delay. I need to figure out how to throttle IProgress updates

Comment: can you add code that will put the current Thread to sleep for like 5 seconds  before this line `ResetStats();`

Comment: Adding a 1 millisecond delay before ResetStats() fixes the issue, but I didn't use Thread.Sleep, only used Task.Delay. The main issue is that there's so many UI updates it locks the UI thread, I guess I'll figure out something to fix that when I get more advanced in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that IProgress was refreshing the UI so much that it was blocking the UI thread, causing the await to not function properly. Adding a delay after the result fixed the issue.

Will need to use a timer or a reactive method instead to fix it as opposed to a Band-Aid fix.